# open_basedir restriction when parsing LESS files

Tags: less, file-permissions, php, open-basedir

I got a warning when parsing my "Twitter BootStrap" files and saving them on disk in my less-cache folder.

> Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/../../lib/bootstrap/less/reset.less.less) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/modules/wp-less/lessc/lessc.inc.php on line 80

I'm using (for example) `@import "../../lib/bootstrap/less/reset.less";` in the main file that I'm parsing.

The funky thing is, that the first stylesheet gets the extension two times: `reset.less.less` - the other ones not. Another thing that keeps me wondering, is why the heck there's a leading `/` in front of the files.

---

Some data about the environment and server:

- PHP 5.3.3
- Wordpress 3.4.2
- The [WP-LESS Plugin](https://github.com/sanchothefat/wp-less) (yes, I commit to this repo), which uses the [LESSc library](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp) - which throws the error from [here](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/blob/master/lessc.inc.php#L80).

*`php.ini`*

```
include_path = ".:..:"
upload_temp_dir _no value/not set_
open_basedir = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/:/tmp/"
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You have a simple misconfiguration which might be also made more bold due to some flaws in `lessc.inc.php`. I suggest you file a bug report with the WP plugin fix it and the lessc implementation - it might have been designed with relative paths in mind. You can offer the fix to upstream as well when it's done. To solve the concrete problem use absolute/fully qualified path names.

Comment: @hakre thanks for stopping by. As I wrote, I commited to the plugin (but not lessc), so I'd file a bug report to mostly myself :/ The question is: Where exactly is my "missconfiguration"?